# Storing non-string value in QStandardItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

Here's an MRE:

```
import sys, datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 800)
        self.main_splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self)
        self.main_splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_splitter) 
        self.tree_view = MyTreeView(self.main_splitter)
        self.right_panel = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.main_splitter)
        self.right_panel.setStyleSheet("background-color: green");

class MyTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setModel(MyTreeModel())
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

class MyTreeModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        item0_0 = QtGui.QStandardItem('blip')
        item0_1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('2000-01-01')
        self.invisibleRootItem().appendRow([item0_0, item0_1])
        item1_0 = QtGui.QStandardItem('bubble')
        item1_1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('')
        self.invisibleRootItem().appendRow([item1_0, item1_1])
        
    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        original_value = value
        
        # if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        #     if index.column() == 1:
        #         if value.strip() == '':
        #             value = None 
        #         else:
        #             try:
        #                 value = datetime.date.fromisoformat(value)
        #             except ValueError as e:
        #                 print(f'**** value could not be parsed as date: |{value}| - value not changed')
        #                 return False
        
        return_val = super().setData(index, value, role)
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            item = self.itemFromIndex(index)
            assert item.text() == original_value, f'item.text() |{item.text()}| original_value |{original_value}|'
        return return_val
    
    # def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    #     value = super().data(index, role)
    #     if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
    #         if index.column() == 1:
    #             value = '' if value == None else str(value)
    #     elif role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
    #         if index.column() == 1:
    #             if value == '':
    #                 value = None
    #     return value

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

The second column here is a date column: only valid dates (or empty string) should be accepted.

If you uncomment the commented-out lines you will see what I tried to do: my idea was to store not a `str` but a `datetime.date` in the second column of the model. Modifying `setData()` also meant I had to modify `data()` (NB taking account of the fact that you may find a string initially, before any edit).

The idea is that whenever the user modifies a date (press F2 to edit in the 2nd column, enter a new valid date, or no date, press Enter), the value stored should be a `datetime.date` (or `None`). But to my surprise if I try to do this, this `assert` fails: the model data appears to have been updated OK by `super().setData(index, value, role)`, but `item.text()`, confusingly, has not changed: although visibly the user can see that it *has* changed.

With these commented-out lines commented out, the `assert` does not fail.

What's the explanation for this? I find it difficult to believe that it is not recommended to store data other than strings in a `QStandardItemModel`, so I presume I am doing something wrong regarding the "updating" of the item.

I tried inserting the following (after `super().setData(...)`):

```
if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole and index.column() == 1:
    item = self.itemFromIndex(index)
    item.setText(original_value)
```

... but this doesn't work: `item.setText(...)` triggers another call to `setData()` (with a string) and multiple confusing `EditRole` and `DataRole` calls to `data()`, which in fact deliver string values and `None` values.

I also surmise that the delegate may have a role to play here... by default the delegate's editor is a `QLineEdit`, and it appears that the delegate's method `setModelData` is responsible for calling the model's `setData` method.

However, by testing the value of `item.text()` both *before* and after calling `super().setData(...)` it is possible to ascertain that it is indeed that `super()` call which changes the text in the item. But only, apparently, if `value` is a string!

Until further notice, I assume that unless you completely re-implement the data storage mechanism here, you have to be content with storing only strings in a `QStandardItemModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of unnecessarily complicating things you could use QDate which has the same functionality as datetime.date and is handled natively by Qt.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd"


class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit):
            editor.setDisplayFormat(DATE_FORMAT)
            editor.setCalendarPopup(True)
        return editor


class MyTreeModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        item0_0 = QtGui.QStandardItem("blip")

        dt0 = QtCore.QDate.fromString("2000-01-01", DATE_FORMAT)
        print(dt0.toPyDate(), dt0.toString(DATE_FORMAT))
        item0_1 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        item0_1.setData(dt0, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.invisibleRootItem().appendRow([item0_0, item0_1])
        item1_0 = QtGui.QStandardItem("bubble")
        item1_1 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        dt1 = QtCore.QDate()
        assert dt1.isNull()
        assert not dt1.isValid()
        item1_1.setData(dt1, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.invisibleRootItem().appendRow([item1_0, item1_1])


class MyTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        model = MyTreeModel()
        self.setModel(model)
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        delegate = MyDelegate()
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 800)
        self.main_splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self)
        self.main_splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_splitter)
        self.tree_view = MyTreeView(self.main_splitter)
        self.right_panel = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.main_splitter)
        self.right_panel.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I hadn't realised QStandardItem has `data` and `setData` methods. I wonder how this relates to the model's `data` and `setData` methods: no doubt I'll understand more one day.

Comment: @mikerodent `data()` and `setData()` of QStandardItemModel get the item using `itemFromIndex()` and then calls the relative function of the QStandardItem, if found. As usual, if you want to understand how it works, look at the sources: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/itemmodels/qstandarditemmodel.cpp.html

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. I was going to look at the source in due course. NB there is a slight prob with eyllanesc's use of QDateTimeEdit, which clearly gets created automatically if you use QDate: it seems quite difficult to allow the user to enter a "none" date. I may have to extend this QDateTimeEdit in some way...

Answer (score 0):

This is by way of a supplement to eyllanesc's great answer. I really really really want to be able to enter a **null date**!

In fact I'm not keen on this `QDateTimeEdit` + popup solution, so I've chosen just to use a `QLineEdit` for my editor, with `QDate` data values. A blank string then translates to a null `QDate`.

But I first used a `QDateEdit`, and wanted to be able to set a null date value. There is a bit of frustration out there on this subject. There may be a more elegant solution using a validator but this, hacky though it is, seemed to do the job:

```
class MyDateEdit(QtWidgets.QDateEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.null_date = False
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Delete):
            self.null_date = True
            press_return_key = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
            QtWidgets.QApplication.sendEvent(self, press_return_key)
            return
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        print(f'parent {parent} type {type(parent)}')
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit):
            # use the subclass instead:
            editor = MyDateEdit(parent)
            editor.setDisplayFormat(DATE_FORMAT)
            editor.setCalendarPopup(True)
        return editor
    
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if editor.null_date:
            # as far as I'm aware, this is pretty much all that setModelData does*
            model.setData(index, None)
        else:
            super().setModelData(editor, model, index)
```

Pressing "Delete" once you've started editing and the editing session ends instantly, setting the value to None in the model. A message box of confirmation might be a nice thing to add.

* [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp.html#_ZNK19QStyledItemDelegate12setModelDataEP7QWidgetP18QAbstractItemModelRK11QModelIndex) of `setModelData`